# Specify a custom trust store to connect quarkus app to LDAPS

Tags: quarkus

I have a quarkus app that needs to connect to an LDAP server through an ssl connection. I was able to make it work specifying a custom trustStore using the system property *javax.net.ssl.trustStore*. Something similar to what is suggested for [native executables](https://quarkus.io/guides/native-and-ssl):

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass -jar ./quarkus-run.jar
```

Is this the only possible way? I looked a the doc but I couldn't find a way to specify the trust store path using a quarkus property.

With this solution I would need to modify the Dockerfile used to build the image, and that is something I would prefer not to do: connect to ldaps it's a runtime option, when it's not required the trust store is not necessary.

Marco.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation and the only way I found was using this params:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=src/main/resources/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case a workaround solution is:

```
    import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;
    import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
    import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;

    
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class StartupBean {
      //At startup
      void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", customTruststorePath);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", customTrustStorePwd);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", customTrustStoreType);
      }
   }
```

But it is not a good practice...